# How can I disable automatic Windows 7/8/10 audio ducking?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10, audio, operating-systems

Windows, apparently, has a built-in audio ducking feature which is very annoying (to me at least). When two or more audio sources are playing and the maximum audio volume exceeds 100% the OS applies a limiter instead of clipping the audio. It has nothing to do with the Communications settings (Right Click Speaker Icon -> Sounds -> Communications tab) in case you think it is. Windows XP won't do that. I didn't test it on Vista.

EDIT: I found that the component I'm talking about is called CAudioLimiter

Comment: Thing about digital audio is it's **not** a sportsman. It simply cannot, according to all the laws of physics, give more than 100%. Brick-wall limiters are what **must** be employed to prevent clipping [horrible crunchy noises/square waves/damaged hearing/etc]

Comment: That's the point. I want it to clip. Windows XP clips it. Windows 10 doesn't.

Comment: Then I'm out. I'm a sound engineer by trade. if you want it to clip... good luck.... & remember to buy new speakers every so often, as clipping will kill them stone dead... [i'm pretty sure you have no clue what hard digital clipping sounds like, btw, you've been partially-protected by some kind of over-run inhibitor in every audio rig you've ever heard. I used to master to  Sony-F1 in the 80s... now ***that*** was clipping :/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 solution

Right click on your volume control, then pick your playback devices tab. Right click on your speakers, then choose "Enhancements". In the scroll bar area, check "Loudness Equalization".

Comment: I'm currently on Windows 10. I don't have that tab. On previous versions of Windows I checked everything on the Enhancements tab and nothing worked. I think it's an internal Windows "feature".

Answer (score -1):

type 'mmsys.cpl' in the search bar to bring up the Windows Sound Control Panel - that's where the 'Playback' tab is -> click on 'Enhancements' and you'll see the 'Loudness Equalization' option

Comment: That's the same thing as in the other answer posted in 2018

Comment: Hmm, I don't see another answer (although it does say '2 Answers') @gronostaj

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/1333418). Posted by [Joy Singh](https://superuser.com/users/892663/joy-singh) on 2018-06-22